# Dynamically parsing JSON arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, nested

I'm trying to parse a JSON file stored locally on my machine in JavaScript in discord.js (v12). This JSON has several keys and values:

```json
{
    "name": "Robert",
    "rank": "Owner",
    
    "hobbies": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "gaming"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "listening to music"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "vibing"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "driving down the highway"
    }],

    "roles": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Founder"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Premium Member"
    }]
}
```

I want to send the above in a message on Discord as follows:

```
name: Robert
rank: Owner
hobbies: gaming, listening to music, vibing, driving down the highway
roles: Founder, Premium Member
```

I also want this to be dynamic. Meaning my code should adapt if a new key and value is added to the current set.

With the current code used, this is my result:

```
name: Robert
rank: Owner
hobbies: gaming, listening to music, vibing, driving down the highway
```

This is my current code:

```js
let noted = ``
var raw = fs.readFileSync(name)
var obj = JSON.parse(raw)
    
for (var item in obj) {

    if (obj[item] instanceof Object) {
        for (var i in obj.hobbies) {
            noted += `${obj.hobbies[i].name}, `
        }
    } else {
        noted += `${item}: ${obj[item]}\n`
        noted += `hobbies: `
    }
}

message.channel.send(noted)
```

The variable `name` is `const name = require("./names.json");` at the top of the code.

This code works fine with `name`, `rank` and `hobbies`.

`roles` has to be manually checked in the for loop if I want it to be visible. My goal is to cause any new keys to be added to be automatically detected and added into the `noted` variable.

I've seen something similar done using `map()`, but I tried it without getting anywhere good. This is rather sloppy code as well but I'm not interested in keeping it clean.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const obj = {"name":"Robert","rank":"Owner","hobbies":[{"id":1,"name":"gaming"},{"id":2,"name":"listening to music"},{"id":3,"name":"vibing"},{"id":4,"name":"driving down the highway"}],"roles":[{"id":1,"name":"Founder"},{"id":2,"name":"Premium Member"}]};

const noted = Object.entries(obj)
                    .map(([key, val]) =>
                      `${key}: ${
                        val instanceof Array ? val.map(x => x.name).join(', ') : val
                       }`)
                    .join('\n');

console.log(noted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan).

I find it a bit easier to read, but most importantly it is very flexible as to which keys you want to traverse.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = { name: 'Robert', rank: 'Owner', hobbies: [{ id: 1, name: 'gaming' }, { id: 2, name: 'listening to music' }, { id: 3, name: 'vibing' }, { id: 4, name: 'driving down the highway' }], roles: [{ id: 1, name: 'Founder' }, { id: 2, name: 'Premium Member' }] };

const convert = (data) => {
  const r = objectScan(['*', '*[*].name'], {
    reverse: false,
    filterFn: ({ isLeaf, context, key, value }) => {
      if (isLeaf) {
        if (!(key[0] in context)) {
          context[key[0]] = value;
        } else {
          context[key[0]] += `, ${value}`;
        }
      }
    }
  })(data, {});
  return Object.entries(r).map(([k, v]) => `${k}: ${v}`).join('\n');
};

console.log(convert(myData));
/* =>
name: Robert
rank: Owner
hobbies: gaming, listening to music, vibing, driving down the highway
roles: Founder, Premium Member
 */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)